# How to use descending with ascending in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query

```
SELECT * FROM member
ORDER BY d_no.member DESC, DateBirth ASC
```

I am thinking how can I do this in Linq?
I have a `List<member>`

I used this

```
 Var Result = member.OrderByDescending(s => s.d_no).OrderBy(y => y.DateBirth ).ToList();
```

Is not working, any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OrderByDescending` returns an instance of type `IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>`.
You can then call [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or [`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to apply a second (or third) ordering constraint.

```
var Result = member.OrderByDescending(s => s.d_no)
                   .ThenBy(y => y.DateBirth )
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi dcastro, when I used ThenBy, y.DateBirth also display descending.

Answer (score 0):

```
Var Result = member.OrderByDescending(s => s.d_no,).ThenBy(y => y.DateBirth ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to use method instead of query?

```
var result = (from m in member
             order by m.d_no descending, m.DateBirth ascending
             select m).ToList();
```